# Receiving "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'" when attempting to replace item in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game and keep running into this error when trying to replace an item in the board list with an 'X'. This is my code:

```
board = ["_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_"]


def display_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def play():
    print("----------------------------")
    print("~~~ T I C  T A C  T O E ~~~ ")
    print("----------------------------")
    print("")
    print("")
    play_option = input("Would you like to play? 1 for 'Yes' and 2 for 'No' > ")


    if int(play_option) ==1:
        print("")
        print("")
        display_board()
    else:
     print("")
     print("Okay, Bye!")


def turns():
    pos = input("Where would you like to place? EX. 1, 2, 3.... > ")
```

**This is where the space is being replaced with an 'X'**

```
def placement():
    if int(input) == 1:
        board[0] = "X"
        display_board()
    elif int(input) == 2:
        board[1] = "X"
        display_board()
    elif int(input) == 3:
        board[1] = "X"
        display_board()
```

```
play()
turns()
placement()
```

**The error code:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Administrator/tiktactoe/Tik-Tac-TOe.py", line 51, in <module>
    placement()

    File "C:/Users/Administrator/tiktactoe/Tik-Tac-TOe.py", line 35, in placement
    if int(input) == 1:

    TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, 
    not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code ["doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)? As you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: `if int(input) == 1: `

This code occur error because `input` is not string.
Why did you put `input` into int()?

Comment: What do/don’t you understand from that error message, and why is the error you shared in your post different from the one in the title?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify code like this.

```
board = ["_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_",
         "_", "_", "_"]


def display_board():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def play():
    print("----------------------------")
    print("~~~ T I C  T A C  T O E ~~~ ")
    print("----------------------------")
    print("")
    print("")
    play_option = input("Would you like to play? 1 for 'Yes' and 2 for 'No' > ")


    if int(play_option) ==1:
        print("")
        print("")
        display_board()
    else:
     print("")
     print("Okay, Bye!")


def turns():
    pos = input("Where would you like to place? EX. 1, 2, 3.... > ")
    return pos

def placement(input):
    if int(input) == 1:
        board[0] = "X"
        display_board()
    elif int(input) == 2:
        board[1] = "X"
        display_board()
    elif int(input) == 3:
        board[1] = "X"
        display_board()

play()
pos = turns()
placement(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, in your function placement, you are trying to transform an input to int(). The input from the user is stored in the variable: pos and you need to figure out some way to get this value into your function placement.

This could look like this:

```
def placement(input, type):
    board[int(input) - 1] = type
    display_board()
```

Where you would call this function from your turns function like this:

```
def turns(type):
    pos = input("Where would you like to place {0}? EX. 1, 2, 3.... > ".format(type))
    placement(pos, type)
```

I also made a small change to how your code runs:

```
play()
while True:
    for i in ['X', 'O']:
        turns(i)
```

Off course this should later be changed to while game_not_finished():
where you would check if the game is finished or not.

Hope this helps and good luck improving the game from this point!